# Application of Derivatives rigorous proof

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f:R\rightarrow R$ be a function such that all its successive derivatives exist in all $R$ and also $f(x)f''(x)\leq 0$ everywhere.

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be two successive roots of $f(x)=0$.

Then prove that $f'''(x)=0$ for atleast one $\gamma \in(\alpha,\beta)$.

My Attempt:

I began by taking an example $f(x)=(x-1)(2-x)$ and let $x=1$ and $x=2$ be its two successive roots.The statement is trivially true.

Then I took the function $f(x)=e^{-x}(x-1)(2-x)$.The statement is true here also so on and so forth.

But what would be the exact proof I wonder. It appears to be a question of Rolle's Theorem.

Comment: Perhaps one can have $f(x)f''(x)<0$ at all points where $f(x)\ne 0$, but the given conditions entail that there must be some points $x$ at which $f(x)=0$, and there you have $f(x)f''(x)= 0 \not < 0$. $\qquad$

Comment: What do you mean by successive?

Comment: @MichaelHardy. You are right. I have edited

Comment: With $f(x) = e^{-x}(x-1)(2-x)$, you have $f(x)<0$ and $f''(x)<0$ when $x>5$, so that doesn't work.  Notice that $f(x)\to0$ as $x\to+\infty$, so $f$ can't continue to be concave upward to the right of that point: if it did, the graph would go above the $x$-axis. $\qquad$

Comment: The simplest example that comes to mind, of a function satisfying the given condition, is $f(x) = \sin x$. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)f''(x)< 0$ for all $x$ is problematic if $f(\alpha) = 0.$

If we changed this to:

$f(x)f''(x)\le 0$ you are in business.

What you need to do is show that $\alpha, \beta$ must also be roots of $f''(x).$  Since f is smooth, and the constraint above, that shouldn't be too hard.
and then by Rolles theorem, there exist a $\gamma \in (\alpha,\beta)$ where $f'''(\gamma) = 0$

Comment: What do you mean by smooth?

Comment: All of its derivatives exist.

Comment: Ah okay thanks ^^

Comment: True.But how to show that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots  of $f''(x)=0$.We may even show that $f''(x)=0$ has two roots lying between $\alpha$ and $\beta$. But how can we do that.

Comment: $f(x)f''(x)<0 \implies f(x)$ and $f''(x)$ have opposite signs.  If $f(x)$ is changing signs as it goes through $\alpha,$ then so must $f''(x).$  And since $f''(x)$ is continuous, $f''(\alpha) = 0$.  Is it possible that $f(\alpha)$ is tangent to the x-axis, and $f''(\alpha)$ does not change sign?  No, because if it did, then $f(x)f''(x)>0$ in a neighborhood of $\alpha$.

Comment: We need some careful analysis of signs of $f, f', f''$ before we can conclude $f''(\alpha) = 0$. It does not appear obvious / trivial. I have given some details in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x)>0$ for $x$ between two successive roots of $f(x)=0$, then $f''(x)<0$ for all values of $x$ between those roots.  That implies there is some minimum point $c$ between those two roots, so that $f''(c)\le f''(x)$ for all $x$ between those roots.  At a local minimum of $f''$, the first derivative of $f''$ must be $0$.  So at that point you have $f'''(c)=0$.

Comment: Why  must $f''(c) \le f''(x)$?

Comment: @DougM : Because, as I said, $c$ is the point where the minimum of $f''$ is attained on the interval between two successive roots. $\qquad$

Comment: f''(x) has a minimum between two successive roots of f(x)?

Comment: We are guaranteed that $f''$ is negative in $(\alpha, \beta)$ but why must its minimum be attained at an intermediate point? The point $c$ could be $\alpha$ or $\beta$.

Comment: @DougM : The second derivative $f''$ has a minimum between two successive roots of $f$ on intervals where $f$ is positive between those roots.  That is because $f''$ is negative on that interval and zero at the endpoints, and it continuous. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\alpha,\beta$ are successive roots of $f(x)$ it follows that $f(x)$ is of constant sign in $(\alpha, \beta)$. Let's assume that $f$ is positive on interval (and the proof for the case when $f$ is negative is similar). By Rolle's Theorem $f'$ vanishes at least once in the interval $(\alpha, \beta)$.

Now we assume on the contrary that $f'''(x)$ never vanishes in $(\alpha, \beta)$ so that it is of constant sign (via Darboux Theorem). Hence $f''$ is strictly monotone in $[\alpha, \beta]$. Moreover since $f$ is positive and $f(x)f''(x)\leq 0$ it follows that $f''$ must be zero or negative in $(\alpha, \beta)$. Let's assume that $f''$ is strictly increasing and hence in that case $f''$ is negative on $[\alpha, \beta)$. And by continuity of $f''$ it is negative in a neighborhood of $\alpha$. This means that $f'$ is strictly decreasing in this neighborhood of $\alpha$ as well as in $[\alpha, \beta]$. Since $f'$ vanishes once in $(\alpha, \beta)$ it follows that $f'$ is positive at $\alpha$ and in its neighborhood. Therefore $f$ is strictly increasing in neighborhood of $\alpha$ and since $f(\alpha) = 0$ it means that $f$ changes sign as it crosses $\alpha$. This is not possible because $f''$ maintains a constant sign in neighborhood of $\alpha$ and $f(x)f''(x) \leq 0$. This gives us the desired contradiction.

Note that if $f''(x)$ were strictly decreasing then all the above action would be happening at $\beta$ and in its neighborhood to arrive at a similar contradiction.

---

Another approach which avoids the use of Darboux theorem is as follows. As before let $f$ be positive in $(\alpha, \beta)$ and $f(\alpha) = f(\beta) = 0$. Consider the point $\alpha$. If $f''(\alpha) \neq 0$ then $f''(x)$ maintains constant sign in a neighborhood of $\alpha$ and clearly since $f(x)f''(x) \leq 0$ it follows that $f''$ is negative in this neighborhood of $\alpha$. From the equation $f(x)f''(x) \leq 0$ it follows that $f(x) \geq 0$ in this neighborhood of $\alpha$ and therefore $\alpha$ is a local minimum of $f$ and hence $f'(\alpha) = 0$. But $f'(\alpha) = 0$ and $f''(\alpha) < 0$ imply that $\alpha$ is a local strict maximum of $f$ and this contradiction shows that $f''(\alpha) = 0$. By applying same argument at $\beta$ we get $f''(\beta) = 0$ hence by Rolle's Theorem $f'''(\gamma) = 0$ for some $\gamma \in (\alpha, \beta)$.